# Risks of a compromised postgresql user with no powerful permissions

Tags: postgresql

Suppose I have a postgresql user who can log in, and has the following permissions:

- Connect to database baz
- Usage (not create) on schema foo in database baz
- Insert, update, delete, and truncate on table bar
- Create temporary table
- Public does not have create on schema public (revoke create on schema public from public).

Obviously this user poses a threat to the table bar.  With the ability to create data and temporary tables the user could also consume all of the server's various resources by consuming all of the disk space, or submitting too many requests to process gumming up the server's resources.

Beyond these problems does this user pose a threat to the data in other tables in the database baz, or other databases hosted by the same postgresql server?

Answer (score 1):

He could generate an unlimited amount of WAL, causing your backup solution to fall way behind (which is a form of failure, if you need to recover to yesterday but the only back up is a week behind) or just fail outright.  He might be able to fill up your WAL partition, leading to PANIC shutdowns that can't restart automatically.  The manual intervention needed to get it to restart, if not done correctly, could destroy your data.

He could exhaust all RAM, which depending on the OS and how things are set up could cause the server to become so unresponsive that the only resolution is to cycle the power.

He could fill up your log partition, preventing other security-sensitive events from getting logged.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to revoke `CONNECT` to other databases or restrict access in `pg_hba.conf`.

Check if all `SECURITY DEFINER` functions [are safe](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/abusing-security-definer-functions/).

Other than that, I see no risk.

If possible, revoke `TEMP` on the database. Many privilege escalation attacks use temporary objects.

Comment: Do you know of any examples of a privilege escalation attack that would be stopped by revoking the TEMP permission?

Comment: Can you provide any references to attacks that abuse the temp privilege to gain inappropriate access to the server?  I tried to find examples but was unable to.  I am trying to demonstrate that the "temp" permission should be restricted and the most convincing case would be showing an example of a user with the temp privilege doing something the user shouldn't be able to do.

Comment: Superuser: `CREATE FUNCTION silly() RETURNS void SECURITY DEFINER LANGUAGE sql AS 'INSERT INTO important SELECT * FROM secret';` Attacker: `CREATE TEMP TABLE important (...); SET search_path = pg_temp,public; SELECT silly(); SELECT * FROM important;`